# Converting object that is a number into formatted number

Tags: c#, number-formatting

How to convert `object` into `string` with a number format applied on the value? The object passed is a numerical value.

I have tried

```
private string FormatValue(string field, object[] values)
{
    result = string.Format("n1", values[0]);
}
```

But that will give `n1` as a result instead of the formatted numerical value.
I want to get a formatted numerical value. For example passing `12345`, I would like to get `12 345.0`.

Comment: Why are you passing in 'string field' and why are you passing in an array of objects when you seem to only want to return the 1 at index 0?

Comment: I just removed some other content from the function for this example purposes.

Comment: Are you passing in all types of numeric values or are they of a particular type e.g. int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
string.Format("{0:n1}", values[0]);
```

If the passed value isn't numeric but a string you need to parse it first(f.e. `Convert.ToDecimal`).

Answer (score 1):

Using string interpolation you can write it as follows:

```
private string FormatValue(string field, object[] values)
{
    return $"{Convert.ToDecimal(values[0]):n1}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
object value = values[0]; // why an array for one value?
if(value is IFormattable) {
    return ((IFormattable)value).ToString("n1", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
} else {
    return value?.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to do something like this based off your example data (an integer):

```
private string FormatValue (object value)
{
    //You can amend this check to another numeric type or add others
    if (value is int)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:n1}", value);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("object not an integer", value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
 result = values[0].ToString("n0")
```

Comment: Objects of type `object` don't have a `ToString` method which accepts a parameter. You'd have to cast it to the correct numerical type first.